# XAMPP not able to start MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp

I downloaded XAMPP xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz and followed the same steps as given in the link http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html#start.

After following all the steps, mysql is not starting.  The error that i am getting is

```
> [root@localhost bin]# pwd
> /opt/lampp/bin 
> [root@localhost bin]# ./mysql.server start Starting MySQL.
> ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

I tried to dig into this mysql.server file but could able to locate what exactly is the problem. Seems like some OS level settings are hindering to start mysql. Please provide some thought process on this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you try with `/opt/lampp/lampp startmysql` ?

Comment: @Joksnet - This also doesn't work's. Reports the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2009/05/30/solving-xampp-couldnt-start-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue/error message because the bind-address in `my.cnf` was incorrect. Fixing it allowed me to start mysql. Might not have fixed your issue, but a place to look for others.